# Transferring a large amount of data in parallel calculations

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, parallelization, mathlink-or-wstp

**Bug fixed in version 11.1**

 Functions like `MemberQ`, `FreeQ`, etc. no longer unpack. Yay!

---

This question is inspired by [one of @whuber's answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2849/12)

Consider the following code:

```
μ = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
Σ = DiagonalMatrix[Exp[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100]]];

AbsoluteTiming[
 RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[μ, Σ], 400000];]
```

It runs in 3.5 seconds here.

Now let's parallelize it:

```
LaunchKernels[]

AbsoluteTiming[
 Join @@ ParallelTable[
  RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[μ, Σ], 200000], {2}];]
```

This runs in 6.3 seconds on a 2-core machine---much *slower*.  It also uses a lot of memory (which I checked using a process monitor).

Now let's suppress returning the results from the subkernels by including a semicolon:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Join @@ ParallelTable[
  RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[μ, Σ], 200000];, {2}];]
```

This one runs in 2.6 seconds---a speedup.

What is happening here?  Why is the calculation that returns the result so much slower?  Is it a general rule with parallel calculations that returning even moderately large data tends to lead to a significant slowdown?  Is the slowdown due to MathLink's performance? Is there anything one could do to avoid the slowdown?

**Warning:** This might eat all your memory and force your system to swap!  This computer has 6 GB and everything was fine.  If you have less memory, reduce the amount of data a bit.

---

### Solution

@Oleksandr's excellent analysis showed that the performance bottleneck is `MemberQ`, in particular that it unpacks all arrays inside the expression tested.  This is completely unnecessary, and it's possible to define a more efficient (though more limited) version of `MemberQ`:

```
memberQ[list_, form_] := Or @@ (MatchQ[#, form] & /@ list)
```

Note that `MemberQ` only tests at level 1 by default (unlike `FreeQ` which tests at all levels).  This made it easy to re-implement the two-argument form of `MemberQ`.

We can temporarily change `MemberQ` while executing parallel operations:

```
ClearAll[fix]
SetAttributes[fix, HoldAll]
fix[expr_] := Block[{MemberQ = memberQ}, expr]

fix@AbsoluteTiming[
  Join @@ ParallelTable[
     RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[μ, Σ], 
      200000], {2}];]
```

This runs in 3.0 seconds now, a huge improvement.

This is just an illustration of how to fix the performance problem, but the code I showed here is not completely safe to use in its current form.

Some notes:

- Changing builtins is always risky, and [can easily cause problems](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/how-can-i-speed-up-image-importing)
- I used `Block` to localize the change, which reduces the risk.  Note that `Block` will not affect calculations in the parallel kernels, so if `fix` is used *only* on the parallelization functions, in the form `fix@ParallelTable[...]`, then it will only have an effect for these functions, but not for the code that is being parallelized.  This reduces the risk further.
- I did not implement the 3-argument form of `MemberQ`.  If this is used anywhere in the parallel tools, `fix` will break things.  It'd take a bit more work to correctly implement this too, preferably just falling back to the builtin `MemberQ` for this case.  There may always be some undocumented behaviour of `MemberQ` which we are not aware of and which differs from `memberQ`.
- I did not implement short circuiting, so `memberQ` will be slower in some cases.  This can be fixed as well.

These potential problems can largely be fixed with a bit of work, and I believe this method can work well for fixing this particular performance problem of parallel calculations.

Comment: I must say that the "speed-up" from doing things in parallel here, even after the fix, is pretty lackluster. 3.5 seconds to 3.0 seconds? I imagine the speed up would even be worse if one tried to do 4 or 8 kernels...

Comment: @Guillochon With 8 Kernels the speedup is a factor of ~ 2. And if `ParallelDo` is used instead of `ParallelTable` the speedup is ~4 . So not 8.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are two performance problems here. The first is relatively minor: `MultinormalDistribution[μ, Σ]` is evaluated in each slave kernel, returned to the master kernel, and sent back to the slave kernels as part of the `RandomVariate` call. In your example, this is a packed array of about 80KB in size: not large, yet not small either, and this behaviour may become an issue in other contexts. This is easily solved by specifying `Method -> "CoarsestGrained"` as an option to `ParallelTable`. However, while certainly representing an improvement, this setting unfortunately has little impact on overall behaviour in the current case.

The second issue is both more subtle and more serious, and comes from the handling of aborted evaluations by the `` Parallel` `` package. The essence of it is that all results returned to the master kernel by the slaves are checked for aborted evaluations using `MemberQ[res, $Aborted]`. Here, `res` is a large matrix in the form of a packed array $\approx$160MB in size, and the unpacking of this by `MemberQ` accounts for the poor performance and considerable memory consumption of this example. The peak memory consumption does not persist, however, since after the absence of `$Aborted` has been verified, the intermediate (unpacked) results are discarded.

To demonstrate more concretely the source of problem, we examine the file

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Applications", "Parallel", "Combine.m"}]
```

and note that we can change the behaviour of this example using only the excerpt (which is complete with original comments, but repackaged to be a stand-alone modification of the relevant code, as well as slightly reformatted):

```
BeginPackage["Parallel`Combine`"];
Begin["`Private`"];

Needs["Parallel`Parallel`"];
Needs["Parallel`Kernels`"];

(* Additional required contexts -- O. R. *)
Needs["Parallel`Protected`"];
Needs["Parallel`Developer`"];

parallelIterateE[orig_, iter_, comb_, f_, expr_,
                 it : {w1_}, others___, {meth_, dist_, ___}] :=
 With[{nk = $KernelCount, items = Internal`GetIteratorLength[it, orig]},
  Module[{batches, batchsize, sizes, res},
   If[ !IntegerQ[items] || items < 0, (* cannot do it if symbolic *)
    Message[orig::nopar1, HoldForm[orig[expr, {w1}, others]]];
    Return[iter[expr, {w1}, others]]
   ];
   (* handle Method option *)
   grokMethodOption[orig, Evaluate[items], nk, batches, batchsize, meth];
   sizes = makeSizes[items, nk, batches, batchsize];
   (* send definitions *)
   Parallel`Protected`AutoDistribute[{f, expr, others}, orig, dist];

   parStart;
   With[{
     chunks = HoldComplete @@ sizes /.
      u1_Integer :> f[iter[expr, {u1}, others]]
    },       
    res = If[
     batches === 1,
     ParallelDispatch[chunks],
     ConcurrentEvaluate[chunks]
    ];
   ];
   res = If[
    (* Here lies the problem -- O. R. *)
    MemberQ[res, $Aborted],
    $Aborted,
    comb @@ res
   ]; (* remote abort received *)
   parStop;

   res
  ]
 ]

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

(I should stress that the above is only one example of this code pattern as used in `Combine.m`; it also appears in other places not relevant to this example.)

Modifying this, either by removing the `MemberQ` call, or simply by commenting out `res`, and then running it (after loading the `` Parallel` `` package) to modify the definitions made in `Combine.m` can be seen to restore the expected performance.

Unfortunately, although one might think up a more performant (or at least non-unpacking) but semantically equivalent replacement, such as

```
Block[{$Aborted := Abort[]}, CheckAbort[res, $aborted]] === $aborted
```

this won't work since `$Aborted` is `Locked`. In any case, for obvious reasons, I hesitate to suggest modifying `Combine.m` in order to fix this problem, so attempting a workaround seems to be the best option here.

### Edit: the workaround

As promised in the edit comment I left when I deleted my initial (incorrect) attempt at a workaround, here is a potential (this time, hopefully correct) solution to the problem of `MemberQ` unpacking. It is different in spirit to @Szabolcs's approach, being based on a modification of the original `MemberQ` rather than a reimplementation, so I feel it is worth posting as well. However, the same caveat applies: modifying `` System` `` functions is something which should be attempted with great care and only as a last resort. This method is based on the replacement of any packed arrays that appear in the first argument of `MemberQ` with an opaque list when the second argument is a symbol. I think it's safe, but there may be a situation I've overlooked, so I still advise caution.

```
withModifiedMemberQ[expr_] :=
 Module[{doneQ, unmatchable},
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{MemberQ},
   Unprotect[MemberQ];
   (* Can uncomment this if we want to print out the MemberQ calls:
   mq:MemberQ[args___]/;(Print@HoldForm[mq];True):=mq;
   *)
   MemberQ[list_, patt_Symbol, args___] /; !TrueQ[doneQ] :=
    Block[{doneQ = True},
     MemberQ[
      Unevaluated[list] /. _List?Developer`PackedArrayQ -> {unmatchable},
      Unevaluated[patt],
      args
     ]
    ];
   Protect[MemberQ];
   expr
  ]
 ];
SetAttributes[withModifiedMemberQ, HoldAllComplete];
```

Let's test it. For this I've uncommented the definition that prints out the calls to `MemberQ` so that its operation will produce some debug output. (Note also that `Range` returns a packed array.)

```
On["Packing"];

MemberQ[Range[5], $Aborted]
(* (message) Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to MemberQ.
   False *)

withModifiedMemberQ@MemberQ[Range[5], $Aborted]
(* (prints) MemberQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, $Aborted]
   (prints) MemberQ[{unmatchable$1305}, $Aborted]
   False *)

withModifiedMemberQ@MemberQ[Range[5], 1]
(* (prints) MemberQ[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 1]
   (message) Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to MemberQ.
   True *)
```

So it looks okay. Now let's comment out the debug output (otherwise the front end will probably lock up) and try it on the problematic ParallelTable call:

```
On["Packing"];

withModifiedMemberQ@AbsoluteTiming[
 Join @@ ParallelTable[
  RandomVariate[
   MultinormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[CapitalSigma]], 
   200000
  ], {2}
 ];
]
(* {2.8593750, Null} *)
```

No unpacking messages are printed, and the performance issue is fixed. (On my computer, the version using the unmodified `MemberQ` takes 5.6 seconds.)

Comment: Great analysis!!  I'm a bit disappointed that MemberQ unpacks. There is a clear room for optimization here.  Merely knowing the *type* of a packed array should be enough for the system to conclude that the array is free of symbols.  Such optimizations are used with some other pattern matching functions.

Comment: Getting rid of that check brings the evaluation time down to 3.0 seconds here.

Comment: I updated the question with a potential fix to the problem.

Comment: +1. One question: why the definition `mq:MemberQ[args___]/;(Print@HoldForm[mq];True):=mq` **does not** lead to circularity while the definition `MemberQ[args___] /; (Print@HoldForm[mq]; True) := MemberQ[args]` does?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov because in the first case the evaluation of this definition is finished after the first term rewriting iteration. It's the same as for any expression that doesn't change under evaluation: symbols without definitions don't trigger infinite recursion. In the second case, if we replace the matched pattern with something new, evaluation is *not* known to be finished until that has also been evaluated, which gives rise to problems. The internal details of this are likely related to how *Mathematica* implements tail call optimization.