# Parallelization of distinct array write access from subkernels

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, fourier-analysis

I'm working on an implementation of a multivariate FFT, which is (or at least should be) highly parallelizable due to the row-column-algorithm. However, i can't figure out how to implement that. The serialized idea looks like the following

```
MFFTs[dims_,data_] := Block[{e,f,locdat=data},
  If[Dimensions[dims] == {1}, Return[Fourier[locdat]];
  , (*else: row column*)
    Do[locdat[[e,All]] = Fourier[locdat[[e,All]]], {e,1,dims[[1]]}];
    Do[locdat[[All,f]] = Fourier[locdat[[All,f]]];,{f,1,dims[[2]]}];
    Return[locdat];
  ]
];
```

which would take on a sample of e.g. $2^{14}$ data points on a grid of $4\times2^{12}$ samples (quite anisotrope) about `0.089` seconds.
Note that the operations in the first loop work on complete distinct sets of data. After that the second `Do`-Loop does also never write on an array entry twice. So that should be parallelizable quite far. However even for that short set of data the code

```
MFFTp[dims_, data_] := Block[{e, f, locdat = data},
  If[Dimensions[dims] == {1},Return[Fourier[locdat]];
  ,
  locdat = ParallelTable[Fourier[a],{a,locdat}];
  Do[locdat[[All, f]] = Fourier[locdat[[All, f]]];, {f, 1, dims[[2]]}];
  Return[locdat];
 ]
];
```

would need about `0.0549` seconds (running on 4 subkernels).

Do you know a way to do something similar with the second one (or in more dimensions that would be encapsulated `Do`s) ?

Any Usage of `ParallelDo` would require to `SetSharedVariable` the `locdat`, which kills any timing due to synchronization (about `4` seconds in this example using 4 subkernels).
Due to the distinct write access it would be nice to be able to write in parallel onto an array in the Master kernel or something like that.

#### Edit: Update

One little improvement - at least limited to the 2D-FFT is using twice the command `locdat = Transpose[ParallelTable[Fourier[a],{a,locdat}]];` to perform the FFT on each row and column. That won't work for a 3DFFT though.
And it doesn't improve the timing that much.

As @Ajasja pointed out the bottleneck is the collection of the results, so some kind of `Parallelwrite` would be really great.

Comment: Are you aware that `Fourier` already is multivariate?  E.g., for $2^{24}$ values, `n = 2^4; data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n, n, n, n, n}]; Timing[
 Fourier[data];]` takes 0.6 seconds on a single kernel; most of that is to claim RAM for the calculation.  (It doesn't parallelize; if you try, it will take ten times longer.)

Comment: Could the bottleneck be the transfer of data as here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/transferring-a-large-amount-of-data-in-parallel-calculations
Also, in your example code it is probably possible to replace
    Do[locdat[[All, f]] = Fourier[locdat[[All, f]]];, {f, 1, dims[[2]]}];
by a ParallelMap or ParallelDo.

Comment: @whuber i wasn't aware of that, that migth at least speed up the sequential algorithm, though my emphasize is on parallelization

Comment: @Ajasja yes, you're right, the bottleneck is the transfer of data. I replaced the second `Do` by your two suggestions and finally by a `parallelTable` on the `Transpose[]` data, which would not solve the problem for more than 2 dimensions. I haven't had an idea yet how to apply your advice to my problem; will try that tomorrow, though.

Comment: @Ajasja - well the number of `MemberQ` and the syncronization actually _is_ the bottleneck but i can't adapt the hint you linked, because my Arrays are still unpacked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I want to point out not only that `Fourier` works for arbitrary *n*-dimensional arrays (as already mentioned by whuber), but also that it's already very efficiently parallelized using threading (*via* the [Intel MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/)). Therefore, attempts to parallelize it further are futile unless you intend to distribute the workload over a cluster--and then, even using algorithms that require no synchronization, the cost of communication must be considered and carefully minimized. As [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law) makes clear, the performance one may gain through parallelization is very strongly constrained by the remaining serial portion of the workload, and communication is inherently difficult to parallelize within the "scatter/gather" paradigm offered by the `` Parallel` `` package. It is possible to implement [MPI-style message passing on top of *MathLink*](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Jun/msg00535.html), but even then, *Mathematica* and *MathLink* are not ideal for the purpose, and you will definitely need a cluster with a high-performance interconnect such as InfiniBand in order to make this reasonably scalable.

All this being said, there's no reason not to at least try to implement a row-column decomposition to see what can be done with it. Taking your `MFFTs` to start with, and assuming that the input array will always have quite a high aspect ratio as in your question, we can get much better performance by doing the column-wise transforms "by hand" with a tensor dot product rather than calling `Fourier` once for each column. This is because the overhead of the function call is significant, and for small $N$ there's not that much to be gained from an $O(N M \text{log} N)$ algorithm versus one that works in $O(N^2 M)$ time (although this still implies $\approx$ 3 times as many operations for $N = 4$, so it helps that the dot product is efficient and well parallelized). Let's write:

```
DFTMatrix[n_] := 1/Sqrt[n] Table[Exp[(2 Pi I (r - 1) (s - 1))/n], {r, 1, n}, {s, 1, n}];

MFFTs2[data_?ArrayQ] /; ArrayDepth[data] > 1 :=
 Block[{local = data, len = Length[data], i},
  Do[local[[i, All]] = Fourier[local[[i, All]]], {i, 1, len}];
  Developer`ToPackedArray@DFTMatrix@N[len].local
 ];

MFFTs2[data_] := Fourier[data]; (* fallthrough for 1-d arrays *)
```

which is a lot faster (and still works for arrays of arbitrary dimensionality). For an array with $(N, M) = (4, 2^{20})$ , the `AbsoluteTiming` of `MFFTs2` is 0.52 seconds versus 12.16 seconds for `MFFTs`, and (this surprised me!) `MFFTs2` is even faster than `Fourier` for arrays of certain non-power-of-2 dimensions such as $4 \times (2^{20}+1)$ , where `AbsoluteTiming`s are 0.78 seconds for `MFFTs2` and 1.45 seconds for `Fourier`. Here I've kept your `Do` construct because it doesn't unpack, unlike the simpler `Fourier /@ local`, which unpacks down to level 1 (although isn't significantly slower as a result). It's worth remembering, though, that both approaches still copy their input (i.e., the FFT is not performed in-place).

Now, thinking about parallelizing it, the main consideration is avoiding unpacking since there's really no way to avoid the communication cost of sending each of the sub-arrays at level 1 to the subkernels. As a result, performance will always be poor, even on a cluster; parallel FFTs are ordinarily used when the data do not need to be sent in their entirety as they have *already* been distributed, and it is then desired to form the distributed FFT. In any case, doing the best we can, we need both `withModifiedMemberQ` from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2919/312) answer, and to avoid the distribution of the whole of the array when only the parts at level 1 are actually required by each subkernel. Writing that down, we get:

```
MFFTp2[data_?ArrayQ] /; ArrayDepth[data] > 1 :=
 Block[{local = data, i},
  local = withModifiedMemberQ@ParallelTable[
   Fourier[i], {i, local},
   DistributedContexts -> None
  ];
  Developer`ToPackedArray@DFTMatrix@N@Length[data].local
 ];

MFFTp2[data_] := Fourier[data];
```

which, for an array of $(N, M) = (4, 2^{21} + 1)$ , gives an `AbsoluteTiming` of 4.59 seconds (of which 0.81 seconds is spent on communication), versus `Fourier`'s `AbsoluteTiming` of 3.04 seconds. So, at least communication costs aren't totally overwhelming, and perhaps on a cluster with a fast interconnect it might outperform `Fourier` for certain (large) inputs. However, performance is still mediocre at best, which conforms to our generally low expectations for this kind of approach.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. I know about Ahmdahl Law and don't think, the gain in 2D might be that much, but it might be in higher dimensions. Thanks for the hint, that `Fourier@locdat` unpacks, but do you have an Idea how to perform that in-place? That's what I can't figure out in Mathematica.
Your parallel version looks great, I think it's surprising that the dot product is _that_ much optimized. I already read about the `withModifiedMemberQ` but couldn't adapt it.

I'm quite eager to try your idea on higher dimensional data.

Comment: So i tried your approach and it works great for the posted question. Though, if the $N$ (from your remarks) gets too large (say it's bigger that $M/2$ but less than $M$), the DFT-Matrix is quite slow. For those cases, using the ParallelTable on the columns of the data and transposing the result, is much faster. With that distinction, the 2D case might reach its limits, when $N<M$ are arbitrary. How to perform the second idea on 3D or 4D data, will be one of my next things to think about.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, I doubt if you can beat `Fourier` in general, but you might be able to find something that works well for you by experimentation. In regard to how to perform the FFT in-place: this is not possible using any legitimate approach, although I have an idea how one might do it (in version 8 only) by using highly questionable undocumented techniques. If I have time to get this working, I will update this answer and leave another comment here.

Comment: Okay, I'm also not sure whether performing in-place gains that much speed, I'm not that far away from `Fourier`, that's enough, I think, combining the two ideas mentioned, where $N>\log M$ seems to be a good barrier to change form the dot product to a second `parallelTable` (where the second parallelTable does not give good times for the original setting).

Comment: Well, if you find something you're happy with, don't forget to either add an answer or update your question!

Comment: I will, when I find the border between where your approach is quite good ($N<<M$) and when to switch to 2 `ParallelTables` - which works fine for relatively large values of $N$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Oleksandr is quite nice and solves the stated initial question, if the dimensions of the array (let's assume it is transposed such that the Dimensions are in increasing order) are quite different, e.g. as stated $2\times 2^{14}$. Though, when increasing the first, there is a point, when the explicit construction of the Fourier Matrix is too much time comsuming. Let $N$ and $M$, $N<M$ denote these dimensions (see answer of Oleksandr), for me that was the case, when $N \geq M/4$, but I'd only check powers of $2$ and not that many different values of $M$. For these cases the following performs better, where i only state the parallel version, the serial should be obvious and I'm also using the `withModifiedMemberQ` mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/transferring-a-large-amount-of-data-in-parallel-calculations/2919#2919) .

```
MFFTp3[data_?ArrayQ]/;(ArrayDepth[data]>1):=
    Block[{local=data,i},
      local = withModifiedMemberQ@ParallelTable[
      Fourier[i], {i, local},
      DistributedContexts -> None
      ];
      local = Transpose[local];
      local = withModifiedMemberQ@ParallelTable[
      Fourier[i], {i, local},
      DistributedContexts -> None
      ];
      Transpose[local]
    ];
```

This is of course (just) the Row-Column Algorithm in a parallel manner inspired by the first step given by Oleksandr.