# MapThread and parallel computing

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

This time I have a very short question.

Is there a deeper reason why ParallelMapThread does not exist?

Regards,
Frink

Answer (score 16, accepted):

May be because its easy to implement?

```
MapThread[f, {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}}]
```

(* {f(a1,b1),f(a2,b2),f(a3,b3)} *)

```
ParallelMap[f @@ # &, {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}} // Transpose]
```

(* {f(a1,b1),f(a2,b2),f(a3,b3)} *)

Answer (score 17):

Many functional operations including `MapThread` can be easily parallelized by composing the function with `ParallelSubmit`, then collecting all concurrent jobs:

```
WaitAll[MapThread[ParallelSubmit @* f, {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}}]]
```

Comment: Is there any chance to get [this long-standing unpacking bug](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2886/12) fixed?  It was described more than 4 years ago and reported to support multiple times.