# Why is this parallel evaluation with Dispatch[] so slow?

Tags: bugs, parallelization

Can you efficiently parallelize this? The parallel versions are much slower than the sequential version, and I'm not sure why. Does `SetSharedVariable` allow simultaneous reads for different kernels? It appears that it doesn't even though the documentation says you should use `CriticalSection` to make separate reads and writes atomic and thread-safe.

```
dispatch = Dispatch@Table[i -> RandomReal[1, 500], {i, 20000}];

Map[Select[# /. dispatch, # < .1 &] &, 
 RandomInteger[{1, 20000}, 10000]] (* < 3 secs *)

ParallelMap[Select[# /. dispatch, # < .1 &] &, 
 RandomInteger[{1, 20000}, 10000]] (* 50 secs *)

SetSharedVariable[dispatch]; ParallelMap[
 Select[# /. dispatch, # < .1 &] &, RandomInteger[{1, 20000}, 10000], 
 DistributedContexts -> None] (* longer than 2 minutes *)
```

Comment: SetSharedVariable forces that variable to be evaluated on the main kernel (not the parallel kernels).  This will effectively make your code not run in parallel.

Comment: So the slowdown for the second one is from copying definitions between kernels?

Comment: Moving data (not definitions) and waiting for the main kernel to finish.   There's also a bug in the parallel tools which temporarily unpacks packed arrays sent back to the main kernel, using up a lot of memory and causing a considerable slowdown.  See here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2886/12  Generally, parallelization is valuable if your calculation take a longer time, if it's not too fine grained (minimize communication between kernels), and unfortunately: if the data sent back is not too large.

Comment: No problem. I can stick with the sequential version for now. Thanks for the information.

Comment: In this case something else may be going on too that I don't understand... why the SetSharedVariable one is slow that's clear to me. But the ParallelMap version (without SetSharedVariable) doesn't seem to be slow because of that unpacking problem.  If it were, only the main kernel would be using CPU time during the data transfer.  In this case all kernels keep working for those 50 seconds ...

Comment: I think this slowness is a bug (see my update in the answer).  I re-titled your question because the problem is not (only) caused by SetSharedVariable.

Comment: Take a look at the update to my answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the follow up. Adding DistributeDefinitions[data, dp];
ParallelEvaluate[data = data; dp = dp;]; in your first example does give the same benefits without having to modify the original code to define manually on the subkernels.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer your actual question, `SetSharedVariable` does not allow simultaneous reads. It forces the variable to be evaluated on the main kernel, effectively disabling the parallelization.

---

A more interesting question for me is: why is `ParallelMap` so slow when not using `SetSharedVariable`?  This observation is not an answer but it's too long for a comment.

Consider this simplified example:

```
n = 1500;
data = RandomInteger[{1, n}, 10000];

dp = Dispatch@Table[i -> RandomReal[1, 1000], {i, n}];

Map[Select[# /. dp, # < 0.1 &] &, data]; // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelMap[Select[# /. dp, # < 0.1 &] &, data]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

On my machine, the `Map` version takes about 5 seconds, regardless of the size of `n` (at least for `n` between 100 and 10000).  However, the `ParallelMap` version depends strongly on the value of `n`: for `n=100` it's much faster than `Map`, but for `n=2000` it already takes a bit longer.  If I remove the `Dispatch@`, it will be faster.

`ParallelEvaluate[dp];` is not slow, which suggests that it is not transferring `dp` to the parallel kernels that takes time.

---

#### Update: evaluating `Rule` on parallel kernels is very slow

Finally I managed to come up with a smaller and more enlightening test case for this slowdown.  In a fresh kernel, evaluate:

```
LaunchKernels[]

data = Table[Rule[1, 1], {1000}];

AbsoluteTiming[Table[data, {1000}];]     (* very fast *)
(* ==> {0.001288, Null} *)

DistributeDefinitions[data] (* ParallelEvaluate doesn't auto-distribute *)

ParallelEvaluate[AbsoluteTiming[Table[data, {1000}];]]
(* ==>
{{0.939300, Null}, {0.947640, Null}, {0.941881, Null}, {0.931997, Null}, 
 {0.925231, Null}, {0.930565, Null}, {0.930977, Null}, {0.931430, Null}} *)
```

This is very slow, and it is the parallel kernels that take so long to evaluate it!

Now let's change `data` to

```
data = Table[rule[1, 1], {1000}];

DistributeDefinitions[data]

ParallelEvaluate[AbsoluteTiming[Table[data, {1000}];]]
(* ==>
{{0.000197, Null}, {0.000212, Null}, {0.000347, Null}, {0.000192, Null}, 
 {0.000220, Null}, {0.000327, Null}, {0.000331, Null}, {0.000197, Null}} *)
```

This is now very fast.  **So the culprit is `Rule`**.  But why?  Is `Rule` overloaded in the parallel kernels?  `ParallelEvaluate[Information[Rule]]` reveals nothing special.

---

**Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on here?**

---

**Update on 2014-03-04:**

I received a reply about this from WRI support and they pointed out that the issue is mentioned in the documentation.  It's the third entry under "Possible Issues" at [`DistributeDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html).

The example there describes the same problem with `InterpolatingFunction` objects.  Quoting the relevant part of the documentation, without repeating the example code:

> Certain objects with an internal state may not work efficiently when distributed.  ... Certain objects with an internal state may not work efficiently when distributed. ... Alternatively, reevaluate the data on all subkernels.

For the example above the workaround is as simple as

```
ParallelEvaluate[data = data;]
```

This is very simple to @Michael's workaround in the other answer, but it's not even necessary to recreate the expressions form scratch.  It's sufficient to just re-assign the variable to itself (and re-evaluate it in the process).

Comment: I reported this to support yesterday.

Comment: I'm wondering what the support said about this?

Comment: @xslittlegrass They said they filed a report, I haven't heard anything since.  It hasn't affected me directly so I have not pursued it.  I wouldn't normally report problems that don't hinder me personally but in this case I spent so much time debugging  the OP's problem (why do I do this?!) that I couldn't let it go ...

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way in which `ParallelMap` works three times faster (V9.0.1, Mac OS, Intel i7, Quad core, 8 virtual cores).  The trick is to **evaluate** `dispatch = Dispatch@rules` on each kernel.

I don't really have an explanation, other than the guess that the dispatch table resides wholly in each kernel's memory and the observation that when rules are distributed, they take use half the memory in the parallel kernels than in the main kernel.  When the rules are evaluated in the parallel kernels, even by `ParallelEvaluate[ByteCount[rules]]`, the memory size of the kernels swells to match the main kernel.  I assume that the rest of the definition of `rules` is transferred.  But when the calculation is over, the kernel memory usage goes back down to what it was.  So while the definition of `rules` is registered with the parallel kernels, it appears that the data itself is not completely copied.

```
rules = Table[i -> RandomReal[1, 500], {i, 20000}];

dispatch0 = Dispatch @ rules;
Map[Select[# /. dispatch0, # < .1 &] &, 
    RandomInteger[{1, 20000}, 10000]]; // AbsoluteTiming

DistributeDefinitions[rules];
ParallelEvaluate[dispatch = Dispatch@rules];
ParallelMap[Select[# /. dispatch, # < .1 &] &, 
    RandomInteger[{1, 20000}, 10000]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {2.851229, Null} *)

(* {0.955070, Null} *)
```

Note that distributing the definitions and evaluate `Dispatch` takes some seconds (almost five), so that overall, the nonparallel calculation is still faster.

Comment: Useful tip. My original motivation involved a larger dispatch table and a longer operation using the dispatch table. Paging issues might have been unavoidable when making multiple copies of a dispatch table as large as my original, but I'll keep this in mind for situations with large but not huge memory requirements and long evaluation times.

Answer (score 4):

This non-answer (addressing Szabolcs' observation) won't fit in a comment.

The following makes me suspect that the problem has something to do with how the parallel kernels are representing `data` internally:

```
LaunchKernels[];

datatest = Table[rule[x, x], {2}];
data = Table[Rule[x, x], {2}];

Trace[datatest]
(* ==> {datatest,{rule[x,x],rule[x,x]}}*)
Trace[data]
(* ==> {data,{x->x,x->x}}*)

DistributeDefinitions[datatest, data];

ParallelEvaluate[foo = datatest /. rule -> Rule];

ParallelEvaluate[Trace[datatest]]
(* ==>{{datatest,{rule[x,x],rule[x,x]}},{datatest,{rule[x,x],rule[x,x]}},
  {datatest,{rule[x,x],rule[x,x]}},{datatest,{rule[x,x],rule[x,x]}},
  {datatest,{rule[x,x],rule[x,x]}},{datatest,{rule[x,x],rule[x,x]}},
  {datatest,{rule[x,x],rule[x,x]}},{datatest,{rule[x,x],rule[x,x]}}} *)

ParallelEvaluate[Trace[data]]
(* ==> {{data,{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x}},
  {data,{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x}},
  {data,{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x}},
  {data,{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x}},
  {data,{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x}},
  {data,{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x}},
  {data,{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x}},
  {data,{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x},{x->x,x->x}}} *)

ParallelEvaluate[Trace[foo]]
(* {{foo,{x->x,x->x}},{foo,{x->x,x->x}},{foo,{x->x,x->x}},
  {foo,{x->x,x->x}},{foo,{x->x,x->x}},{foo,{x->x,x->x}},
  {foo,{x->x,x->x}},{foo,{x->x,x->x}}} *)
```

In the parallel kernels, `data` and `foo` are `Equal`, satisfy `SameQ`, and have, as near as I can tell, the equivalent `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition ``, but one can see from the traces that the evaluation paths are different.

Comment: Btw, if you use double backticks around your code snippent, you can use single backticks inside

Comment: @Rojo - thanks.