# Association lookup in sub-kernel seems slow

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, parallelization, associations

While developing a parallel version of some code, I noticed that looking up an item in an association seemed much slower than in the serial version of the code.
To show the effect, I created the following example :

```
LaunchKernels[]; (* four kernels will be launched *)
assoc= Association[Table[i-> {i,i^2},{i,1,100}]];
array=Table[{i,i^2},{i,1,100}];
DistributeDefinitions[assoc,array];
```

To make sure the association and the table are known by the sub-kernels :

```
In[6]:= ParallelTable[Names["Global`*"], {4}]

Out[6]= {{"array", "assoc"}, {"array", "assoc"}, {"array", "assoc"}, {"array", "assoc"}}
```

First I run a serial version of some example code :

```
In[7]:= AbsoluteTiming[Table[Table[assoc[10], {100000}];, {4}];]

Out[7]= {0.106069, Null}
```

Next I run the parallel version of the same code :

```
In[8]:= AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[Table[assoc[10], {100000}];, {4}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"];]

Out[8]= {4.37772, Null}
```

I also tried using the Lookup command explicitly:

```
In[9]:= AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[Table[Lookup[assoc, 10], {100000}];, {4}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"];]

Out[9]= {4.58422, Null}
```

In both cases, the parallel version runs much slower although there is (I think) no call-back to the main kernel from the sub-kernels during the evaluation which might slow things down.  There is also no passing of data into our out off the sub-kernels.

When I use a table lookup instead of an association lookup in the code , the slow down is not present :

```
In[13]:= AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[Table[array[[10]], {100000}];, {4}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"];]

Out[13]= {0.037059, Null}
```

I don't have a clue what is going on.  I would be glad if someone can explain me why this slow down happens and how to avoid it. Or point me to a previous similar post in case I missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be the same "bug" as for rules and dispatches. For some reason it helps to copy the variable in question in the local Kernel.

```
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[assoc = assoc; Table[assoc[10], {100000}];, {4},Method -> "CoarsestGrained"];]


{0.0354219, Null}
```

Comment: OK. Thanks.  Do you have a link to the posts describing the rules and dispatches bug?

Comment: @PeterB Maybe this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25263/12