# ParallelTable 70 times slower on 16 cores than Table on single core

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

Consider these code(sorry it's messy), why the `ParallelTable` version is 70 times slower than the `Table` version?

```
Quit[]
Clear["`*"]  
$Version  
(*
==> "8.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 23, 2011)"
*)   
Kernels[]  
(*
==> {}
*)   
a = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, {401, 300000}];    
b = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, {401, 300000}];  
Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {a, b} 
(*
==> {True, True}
*)

ht = 2*0.375*^-9;    
DFT[A_, ht_] := 
  RotateRight[
   ht/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]*
    Fourier[RotateLeft[A, Length[A]/2 - 1], 
     FourierParameters -> {1, 1}], Length[A]/2 - 1];

SmoothDFT[A_, ht_, n_] := 
  DFT[Table[0., {(n - 1)*Length[A]/2}]~Join~A~Join~
    Table[0., {(n - 1)*Length[A]/2}], ht];

SelectbyWRange[A_, {WMin_, WMax_}, {TakeWMin_, TakeWMax_}] :=
  Module[{lthA, nMax, nMin}, lthA = Length[A];
  nMin = Round[-((-WMax + lthA WMin)/(
      WMax - WMin)) - ((1 - lthA) TakeWMin)/(WMax - WMin)];
  nMax = Round[-((-WMax + lthA WMin)/(
      WMax - WMin)) - ((1 - lthA) TakeWMax)/(WMax - WMin)];
  Transpose[{Table[
     TakeWMin + n *(TakeWMax - TakeWMin)/(nMax - nMin), {n, 0, 
      nMax - nMin}], Take[A, {nMin, nMax}]}]
  ]

Smtx1 = 
   Table[SelectbyWRange[-Im[
       SmoothDFT[a[[n]], ht, 2]*
        Conjugate[SmoothDFT[b[[n]], ht, 2]]], {-834., 834.}, {19.5, 
      20.5}], {n, 1, 2}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*
==> {0.404922, Null}
*)  
Kernels[]  
(*
==> {}
*)
LaunchKernels[]    
(*
==> {KernelObject[1, "local"], KernelObject[2, "local"], 
 KernelObject[3, "local"], KernelObject[4, "local"], 
 KernelObject[5, "local"], KernelObject[6, "local"], 
 KernelObject[7, "local"], KernelObject[8, "local"], 
 KernelObject[9, "local"], KernelObject[10, "local"], 
 KernelObject[11, "local"], KernelObject[12, "local"], 
 KernelObject[13, "local"], KernelObject[14, "local"], 
 KernelObject[15, "local"], KernelObject[16, "local"]}
*)   
Smtx2 = 
   ParallelTable[
    SelectbyWRange[-Im[
       SmoothDFT[a[[n]], ht, 2]*
        Conjugate[SmoothDFT[b[[n]], ht, 2]]], {-834., 834.}, {19.5, 
      20.5}], {n, 1, 2}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*
==> {25.459674, Null}
*)
```

Note that I have 16 cores on the node and the table have only 2 elements, i.e. `{n,1,2}`, even if I change to `{n,1,16}`, the `ParallelTable` version is still 10 times slower than the Table version. If it is the overhead, why it has a such huge overhead? Thanks.

These are the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

**Update**

1.As OleksandrR point out that there is no `DistributeDefinitions`, but in the documentation of `ParallelTable` it promises to automatically distribute the calculations (version 9):

> ParallelTable is a parallel version of Table which automatically distributes different evaluations of expr among different kernels and processors.
>
> The default value is `DistributedContexts:>$DistributedContexts` with `$DistributedContexts:=$Context`, which distributes definitions of all symbols in the current context, but does not distribute definitions of symbols from packages.

2.OleksandrR also gave an excellent analysis in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/transferring-a-large-amount-of-data-in-parallel-calculations/2919#2919) post, pointing out that the performance problem is the `MemberQ` function.

Indeed if we turn on the unpack warning, we can see it unpacks the array in call to MemberQ

```
On["Packing"];
Smtx2 = AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[
    SelectbyWRange[-Im[SmoothDFT[a[[n]], ht, 2]*
        Conjugate[SmoothDFT[b[[n]], ht, 2]]], {-834., 834.}, {19.5, 20.5}], {n, 1, 2}];]
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to MemberQ. >>

```
(*{25.557433, Null}*)
```

However a second evaluation is much faster even the array still unpacks

```
ClearSystemCache[]
Smtx2 = AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[
    SelectbyWRange[-Im[SmoothDFT[a[[n]], ht, 2]*
        Conjugate[SmoothDFT[b[[n]], ht, 2]]], {-834., 834.}, {19.5, 20.5}], {n, 1, 2}];]
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to MemberQ. >>

```
(*{0.156995, Null}*)
```

If we use the temporary fix of `MemberQ` proposed by Szabolcs in the same post, then the unpack warning is gone, but the evaluation is still slow.

```
Quit[]
On["Packing"];

(*need to reevaluate all the definition code above*)

memberQ[list_, form_] := Or @@ (MatchQ[#, form] & /@ list)
ClearAll[fix]
SetAttributes[fix, HoldAll]
fix[expr_] := Block[{MemberQ = memberQ}, expr]

Smtx2 = fix@
  AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[SelectbyWRange[-Im[
        SmoothDFT[a[[n]], ht, 2]*
         Conjugate[SmoothDFT[b[[n]], ht, 2]]], {-834., 834.}, {19.5, 
       20.5}], {n, 1, 2}];]
(*{25.192359,Null}*)
```

So how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see any `DistributeDefinitions` here. Also, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/).

Comment: @OleksandrR. Sorry for the delay, but why do we need `DistributeDefinitions`? I thought `ParallelTable` will automatically distribute the calculation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That would slow down things even more as the main kernel would need to be accessed for every single calculation (every single element of the computed list).

Comment: I tried on v8 now and I still can't reproduce.  See my comment about memory usage though.

Comment: @Szabolcs  Nevermind: I got a significant speed-up with `SetSharedVariables` when `n` goes up to only `2`, as in the OP's question.  If I make it go up to `16`, it becomes slower.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It could be because SetSharedVariable avoids the memory issue.

Answer (score 6):

Short version:

I tested your code with a slight rewrite on v9, and I cannot reproduce the slowdown. I get a slight speedup, precisely as expected.

---

I tested your code with version 9 on a 4-core machine.  Note that this CPU has hyper-threading so Mathematica is actually running 8 subkernels.

To try to isolate your specific code from the problem, I packaged it up into a "blackbox" function.  Let's just define it and forget about what it does exactly for a moment.

```
blackbox[{a_, b_}] := SelectbyWRange[-Im[SmoothDFT[a, ht, 2]*Conjugate[SmoothDFT[b, ht, 2]]], {-834., 834.}, {19.5, 20.5}]
```

Notice that you only use the `Table` index `n` for indexing into an array, so the problem can be reformulated as a `Map`.  This way `ParallelMap` will avoid transferring *all* of the input vectors to *all* subkernels.  It'll only transfer those parts that need to be processed.  This'll reduce the transfer time, and it'll reduce the memory usage.  `a` and `b` together take 1.8 GB of memory.  If you duplicate them 16 times, you'll need at least 17*1.8 = 31 GB of memory in your machine.  This may actually be the cause of the slowdown you see.

Let's define

```
c = Transpose[{a, b}];
```

Then the calculation is simply

```
blackbox /@ c
```

Since I'm impatient, I only fed part of `c` to the function and used

```
blackbox /@ Take[c, 64];
```

for benchmarking.  Note that to achieve a reasonable speedup, you should use an input vector which is longer than the number of cores you have, preferably much longer.  In your example you use only 2 on a 16 core machine.  This doesn't make much sense: it would give a 2x speedup at most.

Now let's do the benchmarking.  On my four core machine I get:

```
Timing[blackbox /@ Take[c, 64];]  --> 28 s
AbsoluteTiming[blackbox /@ Take[c, 64];] --> 9.4 s
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelMap[blackbox, Take[c, 64]];] --> 6.9 s
```

Notice that `Timing` gives a 3 times longer time than `AbsoluteTiming` for the sequential `Map`.  This is because it measures the time for each CPU core separately, then adds them up.  Checking the task manager, I see that the sequential calculation uses 300% CPU, i.e. 3 cores are running at the same time.  Something in `blackbox` must already be parallelized in the kernel directly (most likely `Fourier`).

Thus by further high level parallelization we can expect a speedup of about 30% that corresponds to going from a 300% CPU usage to a full 400% in this four-core machine.  This is exactly what happens on my machine when I use `ParallelMap`: the timing went from 9.4 s to 6.9 s.

So, at least with version 9.0.1 and when using `Map`, I can't reproduce the slowdown.  I get the expected speedup.  But I did not test with v8.

---

**Update:** I have now tested with Mathematica 8.0.4.  The results are the same as with 9.  I cannot reproduce the problem.