# ParallelTable slow down, Region functions

Tags: parallelization, computational-geometry

I am experiencing speed issues with `ParallelTable`. There are a few related problems on SX posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82496/two-maybe-related-issues-with-paralleltable/103932?noredirect=1#comment282149_103932) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28445/paralleltable-70-times-slower-on-16-cores-than-table-on-single-core), but no resolution. The various respondents to those problems *seem* to be focused around `PackedArray` issues, but in this case I really can't see that it would be an issue (but happy to be shown wrong if it fixes the problems, of course).

Viz., I'm doing a bunch of computational geometry and need to compute `RegionDistance` over a regular 3D grid to create a volume. Here's a greatly-simplified example ---

```
f = RegionDistance[Sphere[]];
vol = Table[f[{x, y, z}], {x, -2, 2, .1}, {y, -2, 2, .1}, 
       {z, -2, 2, .1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.235526, Null} *)

vol = ParallelTable[f[{x, y, z}], {x, -2, 2, .1}, {y, -2, 2, .1}, 
       {z, -2, 2, .1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {19.9908, Null} *)
```

So, 100x slower. I'm pretty agile with parallel computing, writ large, and have tried all varieties of `Method`, `DistributeDefinitions` and friends, evaluated things in `ParallelEvaluate` blocks, messed with contexts, &c.

Very frustrating. Has anyone found a solution here?

Comment: Have you tried `ParallelEvaluate[f = RegionDistance[Sphere[]]];` before `ParallelTable`?

Comment: Interesting you mention that... I was just digging through an old notebook and saw that I did something similar back in 9.x. Will try in the AM and report back - thanks for the memory-jog.

Comment: Indeed that fixes it! I _think_ I understand why, but then again, maybe not. So now, `f` 'lives' in the various kernels. `DistributeDefinitions` doesn't seem to work, so I'm assuming that, when the remote kernel needs `f` it is getting it from the controlling kernel, perhaps on _each iteration_? Very messy. Anyway- thank you for the reminder @ilian Next pint is on me.

Comment: After some discussion with the developers, I believe this is due to an autocompilation step, the result of which isn't stored in the `InputForm` of the distance function and gets recomputed repeatedly on the subkernels. I'd also like to mention that `RegionDistanceFunction` will do automatic multithreading when given a list of points, e.g. I get a better timing if I don't use parallel kernels and do `AbsoluteTiming[vol = f[Table[{x, y, z}, {x, -2, 2, .1}, {y, -2, 2, .1}, {z, -2, 2, .1}]];]` instead.

Comment: Also good to know. As more internal stuff gets threading the easier this gets, tell them to keep it up.