# Why is parallel slower?

Tags: parallelization, performance-tuning

I always assumed that distributing a computation is faster, but it isn't necessarily true. When I do `Sum[i,{i,10^4}]` I retrieve an answer much faster then if I do `ParallelSum[i,{i,10^4}]`. Why is this the case? Is there a certain rule on when I should compute in parallel and when I should stick to a single core?

Comment: You should try a very large data set.  Every now and then the overhead in setting up a parallelization outweighs the effect of parallel processing.  Using multiple CPUs is a relatively simple exercise.  The situation will become worse when you use GPUs.  The data transfer CPU->GPU->CPU is the critical part.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Sum`, like `Integrate`, does some symbolic processing.  For instance, your sum with an indefinite end point `n` returns a closed-form formula:

```
Sum[i, {i, n}]
(* 1/2 n (1 + n) *)
```

`ParallelSum` will do the actual summation, one term at a time.

There is overhead in parallelization.  Often a significant bottleneck is [the amount of data that has to be transferred](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/transferring-a-large-amount-of-data-in-parallel-calculations) between the master and slave kernels.  Another slow-down is the time to set up the parallel computation.  Neither of these is the real issue here.  No matter how big I make `n`, I can't seem to make `Sum` take more than 0.1 seconds on a fresh kernel.  After the first run, the symbolic result is cached and the result (for any `n`) is returned about 400 times faster.

---

To answer the second question, I do not know of either a precise or rough calculation that will tell you when parallelization results in a speed up.  Consider a generic sum, where `n0` below is an actual integer, such as `10000` and not a `Symbol`:

```
Sum[f[i], {i, n0}]
```

One consideration is how long it takes to calculate `f[i]`.  The longer it takes, the more likely `ParallelSum` will be faster.  Another is how big `n0` is.  The bigger `n0` is, the more likely it is worth the time it takes to set up the parallel computation.

**Examples**

One way to prevent symbolic processing is to define one's own function using [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).

*Slow function*

Here the computation time is simulated with `Pause[0.001]`.  Even on a small number of terms `ParallelSum` is faster. (4-core/8-virtual-core 2.7GHz i7 MacBook Pro.)  It's important to start with fresh kernels, since some results and parallelization set-up are cached.

```
Quit[]

f[i_?NumericQ] := (Pause[0.001]; i);
Table[{Sum[1. f[i], {i, 2^n}] // AbsoluteTiming // First,
   CloseKernels[]; LaunchKernels[];
   ParallelSum[1. f[i], {i, 2^n}] // AbsoluteTiming // First},
  {n, 6, 15}] // Grid

(* 0.075313  0.037028
   0.151674  0.049317
   0.299712  0.049672
   0.589223  0.111681
   1.179922  0.179192
   2.336402  0.500043
   4.795604  0.833306
   9.600580  1.740492
  19.218265  2.986417
  38.453306  5.214645 *)
```

*Number of terms*

Here it takes a fairly large number of terms before `ParallelSum` begins to run faster.

```
Quit[]

g[i_?NumericQ] := i;
Table[{Sum[1. g[i], {i, 2^n}] // AbsoluteTiming // First,
   CloseKernels[]; LaunchKernels[];
   ParallelSum[1. g[i], {i, 2^n}] // AbsoluteTiming // First},
  {n, 11, 20}] // Grid

(* 0.002350  0.032552
   0.004389  0.114484
   0.008307  0.044456
   0.016554  0.049290
   0.033395  0.064034
   0.067941  0.089265
   0.133811  0.112625
   0.275909  0.158116
   0.554793  0.407610
   1.123326  0.504677 *)
```

---

In short, I think a certain amount of testing is necessary to figure out each case precisely.  For a one-time computation, it may or may not be worth the personal time it takes; instead an educated guess might be sufficient.  For a program in which the computation will be done repeatedly, then it might be worth working it out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think a better example would have been Sin[0.1i] instead of 'i'. I get the same issue with sine but the parallel function does get faster when I add enough terms.

The question still remains, is there a way of knowing when parallel is faster? Is testing shorter runs the only way to really determine this?

Comment: Actually, `Sum[Sin[0.1 i], {i, n}] == 20.0083 Sin[0.05 n] Sin[0.05 (1. + 1. n)]`, but I'll come up with a suitable function to sum for you in my upcoming edit.  (Sine can be written in terms of the exponential function, which turns the sum into geometric sums.)

Comment: The question is not if an alternative exist but if Mathematica is smart enough to do that. Even in my original example I could probably force Mathematica to avoid symbolic processing by using floating point numbers instead of integers.