# strange timing behavior

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

The following code is from a book about Mathematica.

```
colMean[col_, str_String] := col /. str :> Mean[Cases[col, _?NumberQ]]

ReplaceString[matrix_, str_String] := 
 Transpose[Map[colMean[#, str] &, Transpose[matrix]]]
```

Giving a matrix with numeric and string entries in a column it replaces the string entries by the mean average of the remaing numeric elements of the column.
Here is a test of its efficiency.

```
With[{size = 1000}, mat = RandomReal[1, {size, size}]; 
  rmat = ReplacePart[mat, 
    RandomInteger[{1, size}, {size, 2}] :> "non"]];
Timing[ReplaceString[rmat, "non"];]

{3.296875, Null}
```

Here is the respective time performance that appears in the book: **0.877081**

So far everything sounds normal. The author may have a faster computer than mine.
However, in order to check the efficiency of its code, the author compares it with the performance of some of the highly optimized built-in linear algebra functions.

```
mat = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}];
{Timing[Inverse[mat];], Timing[Det[mat];]}
```

The times are about, respectively, 0.4 and 0.14 sec.

The strange thing, at least to me, is that my machine has the same time performance. In particular:

```
 mat = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}];
{Timing[Inverse[mat];], Timing[Det[mat];]}

 {{0.453125, Null}, {0.093750, Null}}
```

So, here comes my first question:

How is it possible to be such a big difference in the performance of the user-defined code
and almost identical timings in the performances of relevant built-in functions?
What issues affect the performance of such codes?

My second query now.

In order to increase the efficiency of `ReplaceString` I tried to use parallel computing.

```
Clear[ReplaceString]
LaunchKernels[]
ReplaceString[matrix_, str_String] := 
     Transpose[ParallelMap[colMean[#, str] &, Transpose[matrix]]]
```

Nevertheless, I did not get any change in the perfomance of the function `ReplaceString`.

```
In[6]:= $ProcessorCount
Out[6]= 4
```

The machine on which this computation was performed has two processors on which Mathematica can run kernels. (Actually, my machine has two physical processors and two virtual ones and so $ProcessorCount returns 4.)

Why there is not an increase in the efficiency of the function? What am I missing here?

Comment: For your first query, I copy-pasted your code in a new notebook in Mathematica and it runs in 0.45 seconds, compared to 0.09s and 0.015s for the two built-in functions. This is Mathematica v9 on Win8.1

Comment: Related: [Why is parallel slower?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28896/why-is-parallel-slower)

Comment: Related: [Difference between AbsoluteTiming and Timing](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14152), [Measuring execution time of code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32025). -- I get [blochwave's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13162/blochwave) results (V9.0.1, Mac) if I use `AbsoluteTiming`.