# Why is the parallelized version so much slower here?

Tags: parallelization

I evaluated the following code: `spikes = Select[waveforms[[channel]], #[[2]] < thresholds[[channel]] &]`
and according to `AbsoluteTiming[]`, it took about 5.9 seconds. Then I evaluated the same code but wrapping `Parallelize[]` around it, and it took about 96 seconds. Why is this so?

For information:

- `waveforms[[channel]]` is a 2062148 by 2 matrix and `thresholds[[channel]]` is just a number,
- I have a computer with a 6-core Ryzen 5 5500U.

Comment: There's a lot of discussion here about parallel operations in MMA being slow relative to expectations, [for example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28896/why-is-parallel-slower?rq=1). Usually it's because of things like overhead in parallelizing the problem, inappropriateness of the particular method being parallelized, or scale of the problem not being sufficient to benefit from parallelization.

Comment: I've looked at that thread and I suspect it might be the overhead in this case. But I just don't see which part of the expression it originates from, and I'd really like to know so I can learn from it.

Comment: @Benjamin Does the parallel version consistently and repeatedly run for 90+ seconds, or was this a first run and your timing happened to include the time it took the system to spool up the parallel kernels?

Comment: Generally, WL magic parallelization doesn't work very well for doing simple operations like this. The overhead of distributing the data to the sub-kernels is too much. A much better approach would be to use something like `Pick[mat, UnitStep[mat[[All, 2]] - threshold], 0]`, which uses low-level vectorisation that can take advantage of your hardware much better.

Comment: @MarcoB It was consistently like this.