# How to avoid unpacking from Language`ExtendedFullDefinition

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

Consider this code:

```
LaunchKernels[];
On["Packing"]

a = RandomReal[{0., 1.}, {64, 30000}];

ParallelMap[Fourier, a]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to Language`ExtendedFullDefinition.
>   Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to MemberQ. >>

```
(*{1.853567, Null}*)

Map[Fourier, a]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpackl1: Unpacking array with dimensions {64,30000} to level 1.

```
(*{0.289122, Null}*)
```

How to avoid the unpacking and get some speedup by parallelization?

**Update**

By avoiding the `MemberQ` unpack (`fix` function copied from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/transferring-a-large-amount-of-data-in-parallel-calculations/2919#2919)), we can get about 2X speedup, but still slower than the non-parallel version :

```
memberQ[list_, form_] := Or @@ (MatchQ[#, form] & /@ list)
ClearAll[fix]
SetAttributes[fix, HoldAll]
fix[expr_] := Block[{MemberQ = memberQ}, expr]

fix@ParallelMap[Fourier, a]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to Language`ExtendedFullDefinition. >>

```
(*{0.564126, Null}*)
```

**Update 2**

Using the `ParallelTable` can eliminate unpacking and can actually get speedup

first run

```
fix[
   ParallelTable[
    Fourier[a[[n]]], {n, 1, Length[a]}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.215288, Null}*)
```

second run

```
fix[
   ParallelTable[
    Fourier[a[[n]]], {n, 1, Length[a]}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.092006, Null}*)
```

Questions:

1. What is this `Language`ExtendedFullDefinition` and why I always get this warning? How to avoid unpacking from it? I'm using version 9.
2. Can you give more evidence on "Fourier is so fast that you loose any time you gain in the overhead of parallelism"?
3. If the slow is because of parallel over head, why `ParallelTable` is 5X faster than `ParallelMap`?
   Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think unpacking is the problem.  Rather, I believe that `Fourier` is so fast that you loose any time you gain in the overhead of parallelism.

Consider using `Identity` as an example.  I will use [withModifiedMemberQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2919/121) to deal with that bug.

I use `List @@` to intentionally unpack to level one, which is not a problem as subarrays remain packed.

```
a = List @@ RandomReal[{0., 1.}, {640, 30000}];
On["Packing"]

withModifiedMemberQ[
  ParallelMap[Identity, a]; // AbsoluteTiming
]

Map[Identity, a]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.4930282, Null}
>
> {0.0850049, Null}
> ```

Note that there are no unpacking messages issued.  However, I had to run the code above twice as the first pass I got an error:

> list::shdw: Symbol list appears in multiple contexts {Parallel`Preferences`,Global`}; definitions in context Parallel`Preferences` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.)

This might be a v7 bug.  Does anyone else see it with the code above?

Comment: I do not see the `shdw` message. Version 9.0.1 on fresh kernel, screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IhNJZ.png)  on second call: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B7yKe.png)

Comment: @Nasser Thanks; I don't know why ``Parallel`Preferences` `` would end up on the context path; that seems like a mistake.  Good that it's apparently fixed.

Comment: I guess unpack maybe somewhat relevant because if I remove used the fixed `MemberQ` I get 2X speedup? See my update.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Yes, there is a known `MemberQ` unpacking bug as Oleksandr described, and as I already addressed in my answer.  Beyond that what is your point?  I don't understand.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm wonderring the unpack in calling to LanguageExtendedFullDefinition also has some effect. Since in your example, the `a` is ten times larger than mine, does that make the overhead more significant in your case? And also 1 second over head seems quit large, isn't it?

Comment: @xslittlegrass So with my code above you area still getting an unpack message for the function `LanguageExtendedFullDefinition`?  I do not see that in v7.  I forgot that I made my data 10X larger.  I was thinking that if anything a larger working set might reduce the proportional overhead; usually parallelism is more applicable to large/slow problems.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes but I only tried the `MemberQ` fix above in my update by Szabolcs, let me try Oleksandr's version and get back to you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes I still get that unpack message from `LanguageExtendedFullDefinition` using `withModifiedMemberQ`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ParallelTable seem doesn't unpack, and it gives about 2X speedup compared to the non-parallel version in the second run. See my update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10436/discussion-between-xslittlegrass-and-mr-wizard)

Comment: @xsl I was away.  Perhaps you could update the post with your questions so that I might (try to) answer them when I have time, rather than waiting for us both to be around at the same time.

Comment: It isn't ideal in many ways to do this testing on version 7, as the `Parallel\`` package has changed a lot in version 8. `Language\`ExtendedFullDefinition` is new, for example (it is used to automatically distribute definitions). I do agree that unpacking to level 1 likely has no significant performance impact, but I'm not completely sure that the version 8 `Parallel\`` package might not be doing something harmful to performance as well. Will look into this later.

Comment: @Oleksandr Good point.  I look forward to your results; please feel free to either edit this answer or post your own.