# Parallelize matrix operations

Tags: matrix, parallelization

I'm trying to reduce to a minimum the time of some matrix operations.

When I don't parallelize and write the code in the most compact form I get the operation done in around 1sec (is this good? the matrices are around 1000x1000 machine precision numbers):

```
In[494]:= newtotd = AbsoluteTiming[
   fullmat[[nodenumb]]/tempmat
   ][[1]]

Out[494]= 1.006177
```

But if I try to have mathematica parallelizing it (4 cores) the performance is much worse:

```
In[492]:= newtotd = AbsoluteTiming[
   Parallelize[fullmat[[nodenumb]]/tempmat]
   ][[1]]

Out[492]= 2.362393
```

I also tried to write the code in a more explicit form, with Table (this actually gives the transposed "newtotd" matrix as a result, which is even better for me):

```
In[497]:= newtotd =
 AbsoluteTiming[Table[
    fullmat[[nodenumb, k]]/tempmat[[j, k]],
    {j, Length[tempmat]}, {k, Length[tempmat]}]][[1]]


Out[497]= 3.154871
```

and as expected it's even worse. But I was hoping that ParallelTable would do better. I was wrong, I aborted the evaluation after 1 minute:

```
In[498]:= newtotd =
 AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[
    fullmat[[nodenumb, k]]/tempmat[[j, k]],
    {j, Length[products]}, {k, Length[products]}]][[1]]


Out[498]= $Aborted
```

What's happening? I guess it should be something related to passing the matrices back and forth between the kernels, but how do I avoid it?

(of course tempmat has no 0. entries)

(***EDIT***)
The operation described in the first piece of code takes so long because there are lots of Infinity entries in the tempmat matrix. If I replace them with 1. and keep track of their position, I can then change the corresponding entries in the resulting matrix to be 0., but still this operation takes much longer than I can accept:

```
In[154]:= (*Get the position of all Infinity entries in tempmat*)

infpos = Position[tempmat, Infinity];
(*Replace them with 1.*)

Table[tempmat[[infpos[[i, 1]], infpos[[i, 2]]]] = 1., {i, 
   Length[infpos]}];
AbsoluteTiming[
  newtotd = fullmat[[nodenumb]]/tempmat
  ][[1]]
(*Set the corresponding entries in the newtotd matrix to be 0. as \
they should if I the Infinties weren't removed*)
AbsoluteTiming[
  Table[newtotd[[infpos[[i, 1]], infpos[[i, 2]]]] = 0., {i, 
     Length[infpos]}];
  ][[1]]


Out[156]= 0.046682

Out[157]= 2.423674
```

Perhaps you can think of a faster way to set all the "infpos" entries to 0 at the end?

Comment: I doubt you can speed up something as simple as a machine-precision division operation which is likely much faster than the communication required for parallelism.  In that sense I believe this is a duplicate of [(31560)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31560/121)

Comment: However, looking at your timings somethings seems to be wrong unless you are using a very old machine (unlikely if you have four cores I think).  I can divide one 1000x1000 matrix by another in an average timing of `0.0046` seconds.  Perhaps you could provide a minimal working example of the code that takes one second to run?

Answer (score 3):

These types of matrix operations already use multiple CPU cores efficiently:

```
In[1]:= 
a = RandomReal[1, {3000, 3000}];
b = RandomReal[1, {3000, 3000}];

In[3]:= AbsoluteTiming@Timing[a/b;]
Out[3]= {0.087828, {0.350962, Null}}
```

Please [see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32063/12) on why the timing difference demonstrates this.

Another things to note is that `Parallelize` will not (and cannot) parallelize *any* code, only a few types of constructs such as `Table`, `Map`, etc.  Most of these already have parallel counterparts: `ParallelTable`, `ParallelMap`.  The type of parallelization that the parallel computing tools provide is not nearly as efficient as the built-in matrix operations.