# Alternative for MapThread in listable functions

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, parallelization

How can I rewrite this more efficiently taking advantage of `flo`, `dem`, and `Nsup` being `Listable` and utilize parallel computation?

```
MapThread[flo[#1, #2, #3] &, {Most /@ kr, Rest /@ Rk, Most /@ qsum}, 2] 

kr = Table[RandomReal[50], {10}, {5}];
Rk = Table[RandomReal[150],{10}, {5}];
qsum = Table[RandomReal[6000], {10}, {5}];

flo = 
  Compile[{{p1, _Real, 0}, {p2, _Real, 0}, {p3, _Real, 0}}, 
    Min[dem[p1], Nsup[p2, p3]], 
    Parallelization -> True, 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

dem = 
  Compile[{{p1, _Real, 0}}, 
    Min[100 p1, 2500],
    Parallelization -> True, 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

Nsup = 
  Compile[{{p1, _Real, 0}, {p2, _Real, 0}}, 
    Min[(150 - p1) 100 - p2, 2500], 
    Parallelization -> True, 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

I am thinking it to be of the form (currently does not work)

```
flo1[kr, Rk, qsum];

floR1 = 
  Compile[{{p1, _Real, 0}, {p2, _Real, 0}, {p3, _Real, 0}}, 
    MapThread[Min[demR[#1], NsupR[#2, #3]] &, {Most /@ p1, Rest /@ p2, Most /@ p3}, 2], 
    Parallelization -> True, 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];
```

or something that avoids `MapThread` altogether, because I suspect `MapThread` does serial computation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple. Just make the outmost function, i.e. `flo` in your case `Listable`, which you have already done in your first code snippet:

```
dem = Compile[{{p1, _Real, 0}}, Min[100 p1, 2500]];
Nsup = Compile[{{p1, _Real, 0}, {p2, _Real, 0}}, Min[(150 - p1) 100 - p2, 2500]];
flo = Compile[{{p1, _Real, 0}, {p2, _Real, 0}, {p3, _Real, 0}}, 
   Min[dem[p1], Nsup[p2, p3]], Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```

Note that I left out the Options for `dem` and `Nsup`, because they are not needed (though setting `Parallelization -> True`, `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}` does not do any harm either).

The only thing you need to do then is call

```
flo[Most /@ kr, Rest /@ Rk, Most /@ qsum]
```

because *Mathematica* does the threading automatically for `Listable` functions.

**BTW:** You could of course use `Thread` first to combine your lists `kr`, `Rk` and `qsum` on the second level and apply a `Listable` function afterwards, but as stated above mathematica does that automatically, which saves you the time of calling `Thread`.

Comment: I was so close. Thanks for your suggestion. I am going to wait for the customary 48 hrs before accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced that `MapThread[f, data]` unpacks arrays.

Not sure if this is  the case generally or just the way I use it. I always try to use `Map[f, Transpose[data], {level}]` to make sure arrays stay packed.

Much faster in general and especially when compiling!

Comment: Good advice, I am pretty sure you are right on that one.

Comment: +1 for agreeing with me ;) I also noticed you asked a question on this [link] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33610/why-is-parallelmap-way-slower-than-map). Could this be applicable there as well?

Comment: @Sander Did not know that. +1 for your suggestion.