# ParallelTable much slower than Table on RandomReal with arbitrary precision

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation, parallelization, random

So I was trying a very simple example (Mathematica 11.0.1)

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 A1 = Table[
    RandomReal[WorkingPrecision -> 30], {ii, 1, 1000}, {jj, 1, 
     1000}];]
{0.752044, Null}
```

And then in parallel

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 A1 = ParallelTable[
    RandomReal[WorkingPrecision -> 30], {ii, 1, 1000}, {jj, 1, 
     1000}];]
{6.35024, Null}
```

(which is after running it at least once so that definitions and stuff get distributed). It is clearly much slower than `Table`. This timing is independent of the number of kernels I launch - that is - it remains unchanged for `LaunchKernels[n]`, where `n` is any integer different than 0 up to the maximum number of kernels I have (tried it on a machine with 12).

I also tried doing thing like

```
$MinPrecision = 30; $MaxPrecision = Infinity;
ParallelEvaluate[$MinPrecision = 30; $MaxPrecision = 
  Infinity;]; DistributeDefinitions[$MinPrecision, $MaxPrecision];
```

and then

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 A1 = ParallelTable[
    RandomReal[WorkingPrecision -> $MinPrecision], {ii, 1, 1000}, {jj,
      1, 1000}];]
{6.38118, Null}
```

Which is again much slower than `Table`. I would like to know why is this happening, so that I can avoid this type of behaviour.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html#954279335)?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? Which Mathematica version? For me in 11.1 the generated random numbers have precision 30. If you are surprised by the timing: say so.

Comment: @RolfMertig I changed the title (and some lines) and added Mathematica's version to make it clearer. I am frustrated witht he timing - yes.

Comment: @J.M. I looked at it and as far as I understand it, Mathematica generates a different seed for each subkernel and this goes through the master kernel, which might explain why is it so slow in parallel. I tried to define a seed and destribute it to the subkernels with `DistributeDefinitions`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Might be affected by the granularity (which I believe affects batching in the parallel functionality).

Comment: @Daniel It's the MathLink transfer that's slow (because the numbers are arbitrary precision). See my update to the answer.

Comment: Related: [(2886)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2886/121), [(20713)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20713/121), [(28896)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28896/121),[(31560)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31560/121), [(33610)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33610/121),

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I had seen all of them except for the third one, but I didn't think that the arbitrary precision will add such a big overhead, hence I was convinced that there is something wrong that I am doing, as I explained under the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the best way to do this calculation is

```
RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 30]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.312959, Null} *)
```

Why is the parallel version slow?  There can be many reasons, and unfortunately I do not have the time to verify which one it is here.  However, I strongly suspect that it is data transfer overhead.

This computation is generally very fast, but it produces huge data that needs to be transferred back to the main kernel.  Moreover, that data is arbitrary precision, which means that each number needs to be sent over MathLink independently (instead of sending a packed array in one go).  This is exactly the situation where I would expect the parallel tools to perform badly.

You can test this yourself by trying to pass data of this size and type through MathLink (see e.g. [`LinkWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinkWrite.html), or otherwise use `DistributeDefinitions`).

---

**Update:** Here's a benchmark for MathLink transfer of such a large *arbitrary precision* array.  This shows that it is indeed the data transfer that is slow.

```
link = LinkCreate[LinkMode -> Loopback];

arr = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];

LinkWrite[link, arr] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.30156, Null} *)

arr2 = LinkRead[link]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {6.9221, Null} *)
```

The slowness is due to the fact that this is not a packed array (arbitrary precision arrays cannot be), and thus each element is sent with a separate [MathLink call](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPCLanguageFunctions.html).

Compare how much faster it is to transfer a packed array:

```
parr = RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}]; (* packed machine precision array *)

LinkWrite[link, parr] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.004155, Null} *)

parr2 = LinkRead[link]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.005705, Null} *)
```

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate.  Please review and let me know if you disagree.  If you do not this answer might be moved to one of those older questions, or added to an existing answer.  If a merge is desired please also let me know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think I do disagree.  There are several things that can slow down parallel calculations, and the other threads seems to show different problems.   The fact that the numbers are arbitrary precision is very important here.  Try my benchmark after removing `WorkingPrecision -> 30`.  The transfer time drops to 0.004 seconds (!!).  And `ParallelTable` is no longer slower than `Table` (though it isn't faster either on my computer, and it is still not the best way to generate a random matrix).

Comment: Alright.  Question reopened.  Your answer already has my vote.

Comment: I had checked that with machine precision `ParallelTable` is as fast as `Table`, but I didn't want to make the question longer. I also didn't imagine that all the slowdown is due to the increased precision (even though I put it in the title, as I knew it is different from what has been done in other threads) - I thought that I am missing something simple and after J.M. gave me links me to the subtleties with `SeedRandom`, I thought that the problem might be there. I am glad the question was reopened and I hope that others will benefit. Thank for the help and doing the thing with Link, Szabolcs