# Speeding up mathematica by subsitituting numerical values

Tags: evaluation, performance-tuning, replacement

According to [this Wolfram Blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/), one can speed up Mathematica code by substituting numerical values as soon as possible.

How does one substitute before the main expression is evaluated? The following timings show the problem:

```
In[881]:= Timing[
 meanFirstPassage[N[.95* tenDesigner + (1. - .95) tenRandomUser], si, 
  gi]]

Out[881]= {0.46267, 4.3469}

In[880]:= Timing[
 meanFirstPassage[
  N[k* tenDesigner + (1. - k) tenRandomUser /. k -> .95], si, gi]]

Out[880]= {2.77539, 4.3469}
```

When I use the function above in `Plot` it reverts to the slow version in which the inner expression involving `k` is symbolically evaluated.

As noted by the response below, `With` does the trick. My main goal was to speed up `Plot`. Here is a self-contained example:

```
In[961]:= d = 100;
m1 = Table[RandomReal[], {d}, {d}];
m2 = N[Table[RandomInteger[], {d}, {d}]];

In[964]:= .95*m1 + (1. - .95)*m2; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[964]= {0.009045, Null}

In[965]:= k*m1 + (1. - k)*m2 /. k -> .95; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[965]= {0.059908, Null}

In[966]:= With[{k = .95}, k*m1 + (1. - k)*m2]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[966]= {0.008615, Null}

In[967]:= Plot[Mean[k*m1 + (1. - k)*m2], {k, 0, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[967]= {10.182414, Null}

In[968]:= Plot[With[{k = x}, Mean[k*m1 + (1. - k)*m2]], {x, 0., 1.}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[968]= {1.821481, Null}
```

Comment: I recommend reading the past discussions on [performance tuning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721171/performance-tuning-in-mathematica/), [Plot and With](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica), and [packed arrays](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array), to better understand the way the system works. This may help you understand the reasons for the advice you cite, and then it will be clear how and when to apply it in different situations.

Answer (score 3):

I await a more complete question, but for now my best guess is:

```
a = 0.5; b = 0.2;

Do[N[.95*a + (1. - .95) b], {1*^5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0670038, Null}
> ```

```
Do[N[k*a + (1. - k) b /. k -> .95], {1*^5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.3310190, Null}
> ```

```
With[{k = 0.95},
  Do[N[k*a + (1. - k) b], {1*^5}]
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0800046, Null}
> ```

`With` on the outside does the replacement before evaluating the `Do` loop.

---

Seeing your application I can recommend another considerable improvement.  Even in your new form, `With` is inside `Plot` and reevaluated many times.  If you force this to evaluate *first* it will be much faster.  Here are three ways to do that, take your pick:

```
Plot[#, {x, 0., 1.}] & @ With[{k = x}, Mean[k*m1 + (1. - k)*m2]]

Plot[Evaluate @ With[{k = x}, Mean[k*m1 + (1. - k)*m2]], {x, 0., 1.}]

Plot[With[{k = x}, Mean[k*m1 + (1. - k)*m2]], {x, 0., 1.}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Please note two things:

1. In each case above the global symbol `x` is not localized, as a result of the pre-evaluation.  If it is possible to vary `k` directly, e.g. `Plot[... {k, 0, 1}]` you should probably do it.
2. Because of the pre-evaluation you will find that the various lines are now styled in different colors.  See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1731/121) and answers for an explanation.  If you want uniform color lines add the option `PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][1]` to `Plot`.

Comment: +1, Now repeat after me: I'll not time code using AbsoluteTiming[], I'll not time code using ... :D

Comment: @belisarius what would you use?

Comment: AbsoluteTiming[] measures the absolute number of seconds **in real time**, while Timming[] returns a list of the time in seconds **used**. So, in a multiprocess environment (which is almost always the case with Mma), AbsoluteTiming[] could be deceiving.  Try _AbsoluteTiming[Timing[Pause[1]]]_

Comment: @belisarius I don't know... I like the fact that `AbsoluteTiming` is measuring real time rather than cycles, and catching (nearly) all sources of slowdowns.  There are also [ramifications for parallel operations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2267/121).

Comment: When you are trying to measure and kill delays due to task synchronization, or the effect of waiting time in I/O bound programs, you are in need of much sharper tools than a simple clock (either absolute or cpu related). Please re-read my first comment: I was not talking about idle or sync time, just _code execution_ time.

Comment: @belisarius I think I'm still not understanding you.  My point is that if someone slaps a `Timing` on a `ParallelMap` operation it's not going to give a useful result.  `AbsoluteTiming` seems like a reasonable starting point for timing.  Contrary to appearances I don't have a strong opinion about this, it's just that I don't understand your objection.

Comment: I believe my point is trivial after this comments exchange: Just don't use AbsoluteTiming[] for measuring unless you have very good reasons to do it. And when you do, to do it well, you have to make sure that all other conditions in the subject machine/s and network/s are stable (which is _very_ difficult to assert ... believe me, I earned my living for a few years just because I knew a few tricks to do the timming math in a certain environment). Timming[], while measuring only CPU secs, is infallible.

Comment: This is helpful. I switched to AbsoluteTiming in the self-contained example to match Mr.Wizard's code. I'll be sure to rerun with Timing.

Comment: @belisarius Timing may not be a good choice for several reasons: From the Timing doc: "On certain computer systems with several CPUs, the Mathematica kernel may sometimes spawn additional threads on different CPUs. On some operating systems, Timing may ignore these additional threads. On other operating systems, it may give the total time spent in all threads, which may exceed the result from AbsoluteTiming." So if Timing results are compared between different OS they might measure different things. Also see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98/21) discussion.

Comment: @belisarius If you use `Timing` on a function that can use multiple cores (e.g. `LinearSolve`), it'll give you the total time used by each code, i.e. on a 4-core system it'll give you a timing 4 times greater than the wall time.  At least this is what it seems to do on Windows.  Another problem is that it doesn't work with the Parallel Computing Tools (`ParallelTable`, etc.).  Of course you're right that `AbsoluteTiming` isn't accurate either if any other processes are running.

Comment: This is an interesting comments thread, but I feel it is now too long to be useful. Performance measuring in parallel, multicore, multithreaded environments is a tricky business that you just can't successfully surmount with simple tools like the Timings offered natively by Mma, because if Timing results could be corrupted by a side effect of multithreading, AbsoluteTiming figures _are always_ corrupted by any other piece of software running on your machine/s.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating the expression with `k` before giving it to `Plot` works well for `Mean`, but not for the function that I'm actually using. In my application, the matrices are Markov models of a random user of a user interface and a perfect user of an interface. `k` represents the user's knowledge. I used `Mean` in the self-contained example to simplify the code I posted. But the function I'm plotting is actually this:

```
zeroRowCol[matrix_, rc_] := Module[{zmatrix = matrix},
   zmatrix[[rc]] = ConstantArray[0., Length@matrix];
   zmatrix[[ All, rc]] = ConstantArray[0., Length@matrix];
   Return[zmatrix]];

meanFirstPassage[matrix_, start_, start_] := 0.;

meanFirstPassage[matrix_, start_, goal_] :=

  Module[{One = ConstantArray[1., {Length@matrix}], 
    Id = N[IdentityMatrix[Length@matrix]]},
   (Inverse[Id - zeroRowCol[N[matrix], goal]].One)[[start]]
   ];
```

This function finds the mean number of transitions needed to go from a starting state in a Markov model to a given goal state. Here is the function call in my original post:

```
 meanFirstPassage[
  N[k* tenDesigner + (1. - k) tenRandomUser /. k -> .95], si, gi]]
```

If $k = 0$, the model acts like a user who chooses actions at random. At $k = 1$, the model acts like a perfect user who takes the best path to the goal and never makes a mistake. Evaluating the inner expression first in plot, such as in this expression:

```
Plot[#, {k, 0., 1.}] &@ 
  With[{x = k}, 
   meanFirstPassage[ N[x* tenDesignerc + (1. - x) tenRandomUserc], 
    sic, gic]]
```

is much slower than just using `With` directly in `Plot`, as in:

```
Plot[With[{x = k}, 
  meanFirstPassage[ N[x* tenDesignerc + (1. - x) tenRandomUserc], 
   sic, gic]], {k, 0.8, 1.}]
```

Comment: Hi Todd. Maybe you intended to add this to the question itself rather than being an answer? If so, you can always edit your question to incorporate additional text...